# Submitting a 'input type="submit"' button using JavaScript with a Value and without ID or Name

Tags: javascript, button, submit

I want to submit a button using JavaScript that looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value=" somevalue ">
```

I was told that the web page is using jQuery but I have no clue.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: How about the parents? Do they have id, class or something? Is this the only type=submit in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the `input`s in the DOM that have `type="submit"` and then fire `click()` for it.

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    if(elms[i].type == "submit") {
        elms[i].click();
        break;
    }
}
```

It would be easier to start from the parents though, like the `form` containing this input.

**EDIT:**

Alright, since there are many `input type="submit"` in the page and apparently we know nothing about the one we want to fire but its **value** is different from the other submits we can add the value check to the code as well:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    var sb = elms[i];
    if(sb.type == "submit" && sb.value == "YOUR_VALUE" ) {
        sb.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several type="submit" buttons on the page. It wrongly selects the first button that it finds, as the above script was designed to. I don't know how to look up things like "DOM" because im a newb but I think I found something about different forms. There's a submit button under <form action="somename.php" method="post"> and the other submit button that I want is under <form action="someothername.php" method="post">

Comment: Well there should be a way for you to know which one you want to fire. Is it in a specific DOM structure, in a special form or something. If there's no way to figure out which one to fire well how can we code it then.

Comment: Yes I think it is under <form action="someothername.php" method="post">

Comment: And the other submits don't share this (being in a form)?

Comment: They also are in a form but they are in a different one.

Comment: Well that doesn't help for sure, unless we know something specific about this submit to separate it from the pack. What about the value of this submit? Is it different from the rest?

Comment: Yeah it's different! The value is called " Weiter "